# Using python regex to extract namespaces from C++ sources

Tags: c++, python, regex, namespaces

I am trying to extract the namespaces defined in C++ files.
Basically, if my C++ file contains:

```
namespace n1 {
  ...
  namespace n2 { ... } // end namespace n2 
  ...
  namespace n3 { ...} //end namespace n3 
  ...
} //end namespace n1
```

I want to be able to retrieve: n1, n1::n2, n1::n3.

Does someone have any suggestion of how I could do that using python-regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Searching for the namespace names is pretty easy with a regular expression. However, to determine the nesting level you will have to keep track of the curly bracket nesting level in the source file. This is a parsing problem, one that cannot be solved (sanely) with regular expressions. Also, you may have to deal with any C preprocessor directives in the file which can definitely affect parsing.

C++ is a notoriously tricky language to parse completely, but you may be able to get by with a tokeniser and a curly bracket counter.

Comment: That confirms what I was worried about.    
I believe I will follow your suggestion: using regex to extract namespace names and another way to handle the curly bracket level.    
At this stage I will ignore the C preprocessor directives.    
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Note that you can run your source through cpp (the preprocessor) and deal with just C++ code as the compiler will see it, but that means you will also see namespace declarations #included through header files (eg. std).

Answer (score 2):

The need is simple enough that you may not need a complex parser. You need to:

- extract the namespace names
- count the open/close braces to keep track of where your namespace is defined.

This simple approach works if the other conditions are met:

- you don't get spurious namespace like strings inside comments or inside strings
- you don't get unmatched open/closeing braces inside comments or strings

I don't think this is too much asking from your source.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot completely ignore preprocessor directives, as they may introduce additional namespaces. I have seen a lot of code like:

```
#define __NAMESPACE_SYSTEM__ namespace system

__NAMESPACE_SYSTEM__ {
   // actual code here...
}
```

Yet, I don't see any reason for using such directives, other than defeating regular expression parsing strategy...

Answer (score 1):

You could write a basic lexer for it. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when someone asks how to do something with regex, they're doing something very wrong.  I don't think this case is different.

If you want to parse c++, you need to use a c++ parser.  There are many things that can be done that will defeat a regex but still be valid c++.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I did earlier today:

- Extract the comment out of the C++ files
- Use regex to extract the namespace definition
- Use a simple string search to get the open & close braces positions

The various sanity check added show that I am successfully processing 99.925% of my files (5 failures ouf of 6678 files). The issues are due to mismatches in numbers of { and } cause by few '{' or '}' in strings, and unclean usage of the preprocessor instruction.

However, I am only dealing with header files, and I own the code. That limits the number of scenari that could cause some issues and I can manually modify the ones I don't cover.

Of course I know there are plenty of cases where it would fail but it is probably enough for what I want to achieve.

Thanks for your answers.